# Chatter API call request Limit in Salesforce

Tags: api, chatter, feeditem

We are using angular to display UI and Salesforce is being used to maintain database. We have a REST API class created which has the urlMapping. This class is used to find the records.

We are using 'Customer Community Login' Custom profile and need to check the data by logging as Community User.

We are using Feed Items to store chat history coming from front-end. However due to Chatter API call request Limit in Salesforce of 200 calls per hour, our appication is getting affected and chatter posts doesnt get saved and gives 503 request error.

Is there a solution where we can extend the Chatter API call request Limit in Salesforce. In addition to the above, where can we check that the number of request calls on Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

@Salesforce Learner,
API calls can be purchased from SF at an extra cost. API calls are tracked for a rolling period of 24 hours.

You can view last 7 days API call usage report by navigating to  Reports->AdministrativeReports->API Usage Last 7 days.
[image: API call usage report]